# XPages: can a Depositor modify a document?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I created a user Guest with Depositor rights. He can also Read and Write Public Documents. The test document I created has a field $PublicAccess with value "1". To open the document in the Guest XPage using a browser, I use this URL:

```
https:://domain/database.nsf/Guest.xsp?documentId=E696&action=editDocument
```

The page opens, the Summary field is filled from the document with ID=E696, but it stays read-only. If I add a 2nd dominoDocument that creates a new document, that field **is** editable, and clicking the Save button will save the data.

Is it possible to allow a Depositor to modify a Public document?

Here's my simple XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="ABC"></xp:dominoDocument>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document2" formName="XYZ" ignoreRequestParams="true"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    Summary
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.Summary}"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Code
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{document2.Code}"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document2"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Anonymous (with Write public in ACL) can modify a “public access” document so it should be possible for Depositor too

Comment: Should be... yet isn't. This person isn't really Anonymous, I created a user Guest with password guest in the database, still he's only Depositor, but cannot modify a document using XPages. I'll see what happens when I try as Anonymoose.

Comment: Any authors fields on the document?

Comment: Good question, I should have mentioned that there is an Authors field with CN=Guest/O=Org.

Comment: That is what „Depositor“ is for: create a document, save it once, never see and edit again... use „no access“ with read and write public documents... though counter intuitive: this should work

Comment: It seems to be important ttat the related form has a field $PublicAccess. I just removed the form names from the code and tried again: both No Access and Depositor seem to work, when the edited document contains a field $PublicAccess="1" and no Readers or Authors fields. Hmm...  More tests required here.

Comment: I added an Authors field with value "CN=Guest/O=Org", and all of a sudden Guest can no longer modify the document. It seems that any non-empty Authors field, even with the Guest user's name in it, disallows editing the document. Nice (not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out is that the presence of any valid non-empty Authors field (e.g. with a name or a role) will block edit access for Anonymous or a Depositor. My "solution" is to change the Authors property, by using `setAuthors(false)` on every Authors field.